# Can ls output in CSV format with directory and file columns?

Tags: command-line, files, ls

I need a recursive directory listing like `ls -R`, but in CSV format.

I want separate columns for the directory and filename.

Comment: Close voters. This is asked and answered correctly.

Answer (score 14):

`ls` cannot print data in CSV format, but `find` can, when given a custom output format:

```
find . -type f -printf '%h,%f\n'
```

`%h` denotes the directory part, `%f` the filename part. See the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html), especially the section about `-printf format`.

However, be aware that this won't work properly when your filenames have special characters or a `,` in them.

Comment: Adding quotation marks can at least avoid producing an invalid CSV if a filename contains `,`: `-printf '"%h","%f"\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` CAN list contents in csv format using `ls -m`
and can do so recursively using `ls -Rm`